# ReferenceError: firebase is not defined error when using onAuthStateChanged

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js

**EDIT #2**

So I now have the following https://gist.github.com/benbagley/ef13bc70c62f2cc367561e3927a368fd

The error I am getting is

```
Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app).
```

I am only initialising firebase in the `firebase.js` file nowhere else.

**EDIT**

Here's a GIF on what's happening:

https://i.gyazo.com/0446e6b492aae300870a32f8bb2b2aa8.mp4

Hi I'm using Nuxt to build a test app however I am getting the following error

```
[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "ReferenceError: firebase is not defined"
```

In Nuxt I have an `app.html` file with firebase being linked in the rest of the app like so

`index.vue`

```
<template>
  <section class="flex h-screen w-screen uppercase shadow leading-loose">
    <section id="large-header" class="relative w-full overflow-hidden bg-cover bg-center gradient-background">
      <canvas id="demo-canvas"></canvas>

      <section class="flex flex-wrap w-full max-w-xs absolute m-0 bg-white shadow content">
        <section v-if="authUser" class="bg-white p-8">
          <h2 class="text-3xl text-black">Signed in as {{ authUser.email }}</h2>
          <button @click='signOut' class="twitch flex justify-center items-center p-8 uppercase text-white font-semibold tracking-wide w-full">
            Sign Out
          </button>
        </section>

        <section class="pt-4 pl-4 pb-0 pr-4" v-else>
          <tabs class="flex flex-wrap border-b w-full pt-2">
            <tab name="Sign In">
              <SignIn style="outline:none" />
            </tab>
            <tab name="Sign Up">
              <SignUp style="outline:none" />
            </tab>
          </tabs>
        </section>

        <button class="twitch flex justify-center items-center p-8 uppercase text-white font-semibold tracking-wide w-full">
          <i class="fab fa-twitch pr-2 text-xl"></i> Twitch
        </button>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import SignIn from '@/components/Forms/SignIn'
import SignUp from '@/components/Forms/SignUp'
import {Tabs, Tab} from 'vue-tabs-component';

export default {
  components: {
    SignIn,
    SignUp,
    Tabs,
    Tab
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      authUser: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    signOut () {
      firebase.auth().signOut()
    }
  },
  created () {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => { this.authUser = user })
  }
}
</script>
```

The line that is causing the issue is this

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => { this.authUser = user })
```

Sign up work and so does sign in however when I add the above line the entire app just crashes producing the following error

```
[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "ReferenceError: firebase is not defined"
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like you haven't properly integrated the Firebase SDK into your project.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have, like I said, sign in and sign up works, however, if I uncomment the line, sign in then uncomment the line the relevant information shows when I refresh the page the error shows. This is the `app.html` in Nuxt with firebase integrated. https://gist.github.com/benbagley/5aea365aab8787d15d091200189000a9

Comment: I don't know vue or nuxt, but I can tell you is that if you added the Firebase SDK to your web app, the `firebase` global identifier would be available for you to use.

Comment: @DougStevenson Everything else is working apart from that line for some reason, I can use firebase in the console no problem.

Comment: Here's a [GIF](https://i.gyazo.com/0446e6b492aae300870a32f8bb2b2aa8.mp4) @DougStevenson hope that helps

Comment: Is the `firebase.js` file in your gist actually the one located at `@/middleware/firebase`?

Comment: Yes it is @Phil

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would install the Firebase SDK via

```
npm install --save firebase
```

(or `yarn` if that's your thing)

Then you import it where required like any other module.

I recommend creating a module for your firebase app that can be imported elsewhere, for example, say in `src/firebase.js`

```js
import firebase from 'firebase' // import the sdk

// initialise your app
export default firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "REDACTED",
  authDomain: "dashboard-nuxt-test.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://dashboard-nuxt-test.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "dashboard-nuxt-test",
  storageBucket: "dashboard-nuxt-test.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "1234567890"
})
```

then in your components

```js
import firebase from '@/firebase'

// and later
firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => { this.authUser = user })
```

Comment: Ok so I've done, I have the following https://gist.github.com/benbagley/5aea365aab8787d15d091200189000a9 I also provided the error.

Comment: @B.J.B please add information to your question. External links may expire some day and the information will be lost

Comment: @B.J.B that's just a syntax error. You cannot define a variable inside an object literal

Comment: Ok now I'm getting `Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app).` https://gist.github.com/benbagley/ef13bc70c62f2cc367561e3927a368fd

Comment: @B.J.B really looks like you haven't added enough information to your question. Where have you already defined / initialised your Firebase app? That's what you need to import into your component

Comment: See edit #2 I'm not sure what else you need I have also added the components.

Comment: @B.J.B What's your error now? I notice you aren't importing your `firebase` module everywhere it's required. Also, you really aren't being clear with this by putting everything in Github gists. All information should go in your question

Comment: See edit #2 reason for gists is the question with the files would be way too long and StackOverflow does have limits. In regards to the information, I'm giving you every file that firebase is using so not sure why you need every file in my app.

Comment: Ok updated, however still getting the error on refresh